# Replace openGLView with what in cocos2.0 to clear the background color?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, cocos2d-iphone

in 1.0, we use the following code to set the CCDirector OPENGLView transparent.

```
director.openGLView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
director.openGLView.opaque = NO;
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
```

in 2.0, what we should do?  i use the following and it does not work, the background color is still black.

```
director.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
director.view.opaque = NO;
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
```

the whole code is as following:

```
#import "cocos2d.h"

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "IntroLayer.h"
#import "HelloWorldLayer.h"

@implementation AppController

@synthesize window=window_, navController=navController_, director=director_;

- (void) removeStartupFlicker
{
    //
    // THIS CODE REMOVES THE STARTUP FLICKER
    //
    // Uncomment the following code if you Application only supports landscape mode
    //
#if GAME_AUTOROTATION == kGameAutorotationUIViewController

    //  CC_ENABLE_DEFAULT_GL_STATES();
    //  CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
    //  CGSize size = [director winSize];
    //  CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Default.png"];
    //  sprite.position = ccp(size.width/2, size.height/2);
    //  sprite.rotation = -90;
    //  [sprite visit];
    //  [[director openGLView] swapBuffers];
    //  CC_ENABLE_DEFAULT_GL_STATES();

#endif // GAME_AUTOROTATION == kGameAutorotationUIViewController
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Create the main window
    window_ = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];


    // Create an CCGLView with a RGB565 color buffer, and a depth buffer of 0-bits
    CCGLView *glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:[window_ bounds]
                                   pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565   //kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                                   depthFormat:0    //GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24_OES
                            preserveBackbuffer:NO
                                    sharegroup:nil
                                 multiSampling:NO
                               numberOfSamples:0];    

    director_ = (CCDirectorIOS*) [CCDirector sharedDirector];

    director_.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;        

    // Display FSP and SPF
    [director_ setDisplayStats:YES];

    // set FPS at 60
    [director_ setAnimationInterval:1.0/60];

    // attach the openglView to the director
    [director_ setView:glView];

    // for rotation and other messages
    [director_ setDelegate:self];

    [window_ addSubview:director_.view];


    /*
    director_.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    director_.view.opaque = NO;

    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    glView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    glView.opaque = NO;


    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
     */

    //[CCDirector sharedDirector].view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    //[CCDirector sharedDirector].view.opaque = NO;

    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] view].opaque = NO;
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] view].backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [director_ view].backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [director_ view].opaque = NO;

    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);


    cameraView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    cameraView.opaque = NO;
    cameraView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [window_ addSubview:cameraView];

    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker;

    @try
    {
        imagePicker = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] autorelease];
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        imagePicker.showsCameraControls = NO;
        imagePicker.toolbarHidden = YES;
        imagePicker.navigationBarHidden = YES;
        imagePicker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
        imagePicker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(imagePicker.cameraViewTransform, 1.0, 1.3);
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {
        [imagePicker release];
        imagePicker = nil;
    }
    @finally
    {
        if(imagePicker)
        {
            [cameraView addSubview:[imagePicker view]];
            [cameraView release];
        }
    }

    [window_ bringSubviewToFront:director_.view];

    // 2D projection
    [director_ setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection2D];
//  [director setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection3D];

    // Enables High Res mode (Retina Display) on iPhone 4 and maintains low res on all other devices
    if( ! [director_ enableRetinaDisplay:YES] )
        CCLOG(@"Retina Display Not supported");

    // Default texture format for PNG/BMP/TIFF/JPEG/GIF images
    // It can be RGBA8888, RGBA4444, RGB5_A1, RGB565
    // You can change anytime.
    [CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];

    // If the 1st suffix is not found and if fallback is enabled then fallback suffixes are going to searched. If none is found, it will try with the name without suffix.
    // On iPad HD  : "-ipadhd", "-ipad",  "-hd"
    // On iPad     : "-ipad", "-hd"
    // On iPhone HD: "-hd"
    CCFileUtils *sharedFileUtils = [CCFileUtils sharedFileUtils];
    [sharedFileUtils setEnableFallbackSuffixes:NO];             // Default: NO. No fallback suffixes are going to be used
    [sharedFileUtils setiPhoneRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"-hd"];      // Default on iPhone RetinaDisplay is "-hd"
    [sharedFileUtils setiPadSuffix:@"-ipad"];                   // Default on iPad is "ipad"
    [sharedFileUtils setiPadRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"-ipadhd"];    // Default on iPad RetinaDisplay is "-ipadhd"

    // Assume that PVR images have premultiplied alpha
    [CCTexture2D PVRImagesHavePremultipliedAlpha:YES];

    // and add the scene to the stack. The director will run it automatically when the view is displayed.
    [director_ pushScene: [IntroLayer scene]]; 


    // Create a Navigation Controller with the Director

    /*
    navController_ = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:director_];
    navController_.navigationBarHidden = YES;
     */

    // set the Navigation Controller as the root view controller
//  [window_ addSubview:navController_.view];   // Generates flicker.
    //[window_ setRootViewController:navController_];

    // make main window visible
    [window_ makeKeyAndVisible];    

    return YES;
}

// Supported orientations: Landscape. Customize it for your own needs
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}


// getting a call, pause the game
-(void) applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    if( [navController_ visibleViewController] == director_ )
        [director_ pause];
}

// call got rejected
-(void) applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    if( [navController_ visibleViewController] == director_ )
        [director_ resume];
}

-(void) applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication*)application
{
    if( [navController_ visibleViewController] == director_ )
        [director_ stopAnimation];
}

-(void) applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication*)application
{
    if( [navController_ visibleViewController] == director_ )
        [director_ startAnimation];
}

// application will be killed
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    CC_DIRECTOR_END();
}

// purge memory
- (void)applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] purgeCachedData];
}

// next delta time will be zero
-(void) applicationSignificantTimeChange:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] setNextDeltaTimeZero:YES];
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    [window_ release];
    [navController_ release];

    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Comment: Are you looking for `glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1)` where the parameters are RGB/Alpha between 0-1?

Comment: glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1) does not work, i mean clear the background color, not set the background color to white.

Answer (score 0):

debugging on this for a few days, do not know why. 
back to use framework v1, no this problem,